# Call a variable with Twilio API, PHP and HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, variables, twilio

I have errors when calling a number in my PHP file who was entered in a form:

Here the line of code who call the number in my PHP sendnotifications.php :

```
$phone=$_POST["phone"];
```

And my HTML test form source.html :

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[///////////Javascript
    $(function(){
    $("#frm").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post("sendnotifications.php", $("#frm").serialize(),
    function(data){
    if(data.sms_sent == 'OK'){
    alert("Message Sent");
    } else {
    alert("Message Not Sent");
    }
    }, "json");
    });

    });
    // ]]>
    </script>
    </head>

<html>

<form id="frm" name="frm">
<input type="hidden" name="ajax" value="1" />
<input type="phone" name="phone" />
<button type="submit">Get Link</button>
<div class="error" style="display: none;"></div>
</form>

</html>
```

Errors in Chrome console :

```
jquery.min.js:130 Failed to load file:///Users/Joris/Desktop/Test%20envoi%20sms%20accueil/sendnotifications.php: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
ajax @ jquery.min.js:130
post @ jquery.min.js:122
(anonymous) @ source.html:8
handle @ jquery.min.js:55
o @ jquery.min.js:49
source.html:10 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sms_sent' of null
    at Object.success (source.html:10)
    at b (jquery.min.js:124)
    at XMLHttpRequest.x.onreadystatechange (jquery.min.js:129)
    at Function.ajax (jquery.min.js:130)
    at Function.post (jquery.min.js:122)
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (source.html:8)
    at HTMLFormElement.handle (jquery.min.js:55)
    at HTMLFormElement.o (jquery.min.js:49)
(anonymous) @ source.html:10
b @ jquery.min.js:124
x.onreadystatechange @ jquery.min.js:129
ajax @ jquery.min.js:130
post @ jquery.min.js:122
(anonymous) @ source.html:8
handle @ jquery.min.js:55
o @ jquery.min.js:49
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
ajax @ jquery.min.js:130
post @ jquery.min.js:122
(anonymous) @ source.html:8
handle @ jquery.min.js:55
o @ jquery.min.js:49
```

I followed instructions on this [website](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2012/11/increase-app-downloads-with-mobile-app-distribution-powered-by-twilio.html)

Comment: Seems you are opening the html page using `file://` protocol and not from web server. Open it on localhost where php is running

Comment: I'm trying but I don't know how to do if you can help me. I'm on Mac os, Visual Studio Code and Dreamweaver

Comment: All good I did it with MAMP, thank you